# "Show/prove otherwise" en français

Tags: traduction, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

J'essaie d'exprimer l'idée de « prove otherwise » dans la phrase suivante

> L'horreur de la situation mondiale 'proves otherwise'

Je pense qu'il faut utiliser « prouve le contraire ». Cet usage est-il acceptable en français? Est-il formel?

Comment: Comme souvent, cela dépend du contexte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

According to [linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?query=proves%20otherwise) *prouve le contraire* is acceptable in French and may interprete, according to the context, show/prove otherwise. Other alternatives exist; see the link. Note also the situation noted by @LPH in which contraire is not appropriate (cf. the other answer).

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prouve%20le%20contraire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprouve%20le%20contraire%3B%2Cc0) shows a decreasing trend in the utilisation of *prouve le contraire*.

[Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/proves%20otherwise) and Google Translate as well provide the same interpretation; i.e. prouve le contraire. Furthermore, the former gives three other options.

> Alternatives:
>
> démontre le contraire (I think that this has a mathematical connotation)
>
> montre le contraire
>
> prouve que ce n'est pas le cas

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prouve%20le%20contraire%2Cd%C3%A9montre%20le%20contraire%2Cmontre%20le%20contraire%2Cprouve%20que%20ce%20n%27est%20pas%20le%20cas&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprouve%20le%20contraire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9montre%20le%20contraire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmontre%20le%20contraire%3B%2Cc0) shows that despite the decreasing trend *prouve le contraire* is still more frequent than the first two alternatives.

The following is based on the feedback (cf. comments) received by @aCOSwt (thanks!).

*Si ce qui précède est une relation de n'importe quelle cause à n'importe quel effet alors prouve l'inverse c'est le terme qui convient.*

> Plus la crise est forte et plus les gens sont solidaires. L'horreur de
> la situation actuelle prouve l'inverse.

*Plus généralement, (et peut-être plus fidèlement à otherwise) on
pourrait aussi dire : prouve qu'il en va autrement.*

Comment: Comment un scientifique peut-il oublier que l'on puisse aussi prouver... l'**inverse** ? ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt C'est noté:-)! Mais ça convient ici dans un contexte non mathématique/scientifique ?

Comment: Oui absolument : Si ce qui précède est une relation de n'importe quelle cause à n'importe quel effet alors c'est même le terme que je préfèrerais. *Plus la crise est forte et plus les gens sont solidaires. L'horreur de la situation actuelle prouve l'inverse*.

Comment: Plus généralement, (et peut-être plus fidèlement à *otherwise*) on pourrait aussi dire : *prouve **qu'il en va autrement***

Answer (score 3):

« *prouve le contraire* » est une traduction possible parmi d'autres. D'une part, il y a des nuances subtiles entre *prouver*, *démontrer* et *montrer* qui ne correspondent pas aux nuances entre *prove*, *show* et *demonstrate* en anglais, et le mot anglais *prove* peut avoir le sens « se révéler être » pour lequel on n'utilise pas le champ sémantique de la preuve en français. D'autre part, en français, s'il y a plus d'explication sur ce qui est prouvé, on combinerait plutôt l'explication dans la même phrase. Par exemple (inventés) :

> *Some theorized that independence would bring peace. The situation in South Sudan proves otherwise.*
> D'aucuns soutenaient que l'indépendance apporterait la paix. La situation au Soudan du Sud montre le contraire.
>
> *[Enjolras](http://www.gauchemip.org/spip.php?article5058) thought that the twentieth century would be joyous. Reality proved otherwise.*
> Enjolras pensait que le vingtième siècle serait heureux. La réalité fut tout autre.

(L'exemple qui suit est simplifié par rapport à celui donné par [LPH](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32418))

> *These measures were supposed to bring to the populations an increased standard of living. However, the present situation proves otherwise: the standard of living is only feebly improved.*
> Ces mesures étaient censées permettre à la population d'accéder à un niveau de vie plus élevé. Mais la situation actuelle montre au contraire que le niveau de vie a très peu augmenté.

Answer (score 1):

La phrase est correcte et le registre de l'expression est courant, suffisamment formel. La traduction contemplée conviendra à certains contextes, cependant elle ne sera pas exacte dans d'autres.

Exemple qui montre un contexte où « contraire » ne convient pas

The measures put into place had as a basis the granting of important subsidies and would  bring to the populations an increased standard of living; however, the present situation proves otherwise: the standard of living is only feebly improved and huge sums of money are being diverted from their initial goal.

Les mesures appliquées, basées sur des subsides importants, allaient amener aux populations un meilleur niveau de vie; néanmoins la situation actuelle prouve autre chose : le niveau de vie des population ne s'améliore pas appréciablement et des sommes phénoménales sont détournées de leur but initial.

Il n'y a pas de contraire dans le fait que ce qui a été prédit ne se réalise pas, seulement une autre possibilité.

Comment: Dans cet exemple, « au contraire » conviendrait. Il y a bien une contradiction. Mais je tournerais plutôt la phrase un peu différemment (à moins que le but soit de rendre en français le caractère alambiqué de l'original anglais) : « *… néanmoins la situation actuelle **montre au contraire que** le niveau de vie …* ».

Comment: @Gilles S'il ne s'agissait  que de  la constatation d'une faible amélioration du standard de vie au lieu du changement substantiel envisagé, je pourrais concevoir comme convenable la locution « au contraire » (restriction), bien que je préfère l'utiliser  strictement dans le sens de « c'est l'opposé » ; comme les prévisions toutes simples ne sont pas réalisées mais qu'un facteur nouveau entre en jeux (détournement de fonds) je ne vois pas une véritable opposition ; pourrait-on toujours considérer cela comme au plus une restriction sur les prévisions ?  (champ 1)

Comment: @Gilles Au juste, qu'est-ce qui constitue le caractère alambiqué de la phrase ? Je ne perçois pas ce défaut.